# I'm searching for an optimal solution where i could iterate through an array from right to left , then left to right, one each turn, until K times

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can i achieve this with optimal performance in javascript. Im iterating through an array. What i have in mind is to have a "traffic controller" boolean flag which i set the value to false when is to the left, and true when is time to move to the right. Is this the most optimal way?

```
function Algorithm(arr,k){
  for(flag == true ? i =(arr.length)-1 : j = 0;flag == true ? i>=0 : j<arr.length;flag == true ? i-- : j++){
    if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
      console.log(arr[i]);
      k--
      if(k==0)
        break;
      else
        continue
    }
    flag == true ? console.log(arr[i]) : console.log(arr[j]-1)
    flag = !flag
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what? You might want to provide a concrete code example of what you're doing.

Comment: No, just write two loops instead of having a flag control the direction of a single loop. (If I understood correctly)

Comment: (Btw, the "most optimal" approach is usually choosing a better algorithm, which does not need to loop the entire array K times)

Comment: You should describe *which* problem you are trying to solve, before describing how you *plan* to resolve it. You are describing an algorithm, not a problem. So when you ask "how can i achieve this with optimal performance?" we don't know *what* you want to achieve, only *how* you thought to approach it. Also, it does not show much commitment if you don't answer comments here...

Comment: @trincot sorry for that, i already added a snippet of code i was working on. I wanted to do this only for practice and i didn't found a built in method to do this in javascript, so i decided to do an algorithm for that. I just want to iterate from right to left, and each turn the direction changes. When it reaches the middle it stops.

Comment: @Bergi you mean like iterating through a 2d array?

Comment: your code, which might be the only thing understandable is not even working, right? @CharlieRobles . As far as I understand you have a big array and you iterate either from start of from end until you found k matching "numbers". If stating the problem is hard, you should show examples with handcrafted input/output

Comment: @CharlieRobles I first thought you wanted to do the forward and backward iterations after each other, not interleaved. For doing them interleaved, I'd probably do something like `while (…) { i++; if (…) break; …; j--; if (…) break; …; }`. Some code duplication is probably cleaner (and definitely more efficient) than the boolean flag. I cannot really write an answer though as I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve, like grodzi I can see some subtle bugs in your `Algorithm`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. I will take your break aproach.